# Как корректно отформатировать таблицу Excel, используя C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel

Всем привет! Появилась задача из полученных данных перекинуть в таблицу и её отформатировать
Есть такой вот код:

```
       Excel.Application oApp;
        Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
        Excel.Workbook oBook;

        oApp = new Excel.Application();
        oBook = oApp.Workbooks.Add();
        oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        oSheet.Cells[1, "A"] = "Микроклимат";
        oSheet.Cells[2, "A"] = "Зал 302";
        oSheet.Cells[4, "A"] = "Стойка";
        oSheet.Cells[2, "B"] = "Июль 2018";
        oSheet.Cells[3, "B"] = " ";
        oSheet.Cells[3, "C"] = "Темп, ⁰";
        oSheet.Cells[3, "D"] = "Влажн, %";
        oSheet.Cells[4, "B"] = "Мин.";
        oSheet.Cells[5, "B"] = "Макс.";
        oSheet.Cells[6, "B"] = "Сред.";
        oSheet.Cells[4, "C"] = minValue;
        oSheet.Cells[5, "C"] = maxValue;
        oSheet.Cells[6, "C"] = avgValue;

        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }

        oBook.SaveAs(file);
        oBook.Close();
        oApp.Quit();

        Console.WriteLine("Табилца выгружена");
```

`minValue`, `avgValue` и `maxValue` - переменные типа `String` (их значения получаю методом парсинга API).

В итоге, выгружается такая таблица -

[image: Выгруженная таблица]

Необходимо ей придать такой вид -

[image: Необходимый вид]

Как можно реализовать? Заранее, огромное спасибо! :)

Comment: у себя в проекте использую [epplus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus), в справке есть примеры как сделать необходимое Вам оформление

Comment: А не получится ли создать шаблон в экселе с нужным форматированием, а в коде открыть готовый шаблон и подставить цифры в нужные места? Иногда шаблон настолько жёстко задан, что это прокатывает.

Answer (score 1):

Подготовьте заранее шаблон. Загрузите шаблон средствами библиотеки [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/), заполните нужные поля и сохраните документ. Ниже код, который вам поможет с освоением библиотеки.

```
public ExcelPackage xlPackage;
public ExcelWorksheet worksheet;

public void InitializeTemplate()
        {
            xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(OutputRepoPath, InputTemplatePath);
        }
 public void SaveTemplate()
        {
            xlPackage.Save();


        }

public void AddCellValue(ExcelPackage xlApp, string SheetName, string CellPosition, object value)
       {

           worksheet = xlApp.Workbook.Worksheets[SheetName];
           if (worksheet == null)
           {
               worksheet = xlApp.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(SheetName); // add a new worksheet to the empty workbook    
           }


           worksheet.Cells[CellPosition].Value = value;


       }
```

Comment: А есть какие-либо туториалы на эту тему?